# dbt macro to load data but getting agate prefixes

Tags: dbt

I'm trying to have a dbt macro execute a query and ultimately propagate the results into a list, but when I run the query it returns agage.row text around the values such as  `'<agate.Row: ('user_id')>'`

```
{% macro customer_id_fetcher() %}

{% set query %}
select distinct customner_id from {{ ref('table_name') }}
{% endset %}

{% set result = run_query(query) %}
{{ return(result) }}

{% endmacro %}
```

Any ideas? How to just get the values without agate strings around it?

Answer (score 0):

`run_query()` returns an Object that you have to convert. You can use `dbt_utils.get_query_results_as_dict()`

```
{% macro customer_id_fetcher() %}

{% set query %}
select distinct customner_id from {{ ref('table_name') }}
{% endset %}

{% set result = dbt_utils.get_query_results_as_dict(query) %}
{{ return(result['customner_id']) }}

{% endmacro %}
```

Note - Depending on your adapter, you may have to uppercase the column name when you retrieve it from the dict.

If you'd rather write your own macro that generates the results as a list for any query, just look at the [code](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils/blob/main/macros/sql/get_query_results_as_dict.sql) for `dbt_utils.get_query_results_as_dict()` and adapt it for a single column select and return as list.